# If, and Then... Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I have UPC codes in Column C, if they are duplicated, column D shows "TRUE".  If the issue has been noted a drop down in column H is changed to "Yes".  All of this functions as needed.

What I need now is, if D is "TRUE" & the first instance of the duplicate has been noted, I need this to be shown in column I.  Is there any way to make this happen? Or alternatively, if "Yes" is selected in H on the first instance of the duplicate, it is auto-filled into all instances of duplicates.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in range **C2:H**, in cell **I2** type:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($C$2:$C<>"",IF($D$2:$D=true,IF(VLOOKUP($C2:$C,$C$2:$H,6,false)="Yes",true,),),))
```

You cannot do this in column **H** as you will get a circular dependancy issue.

Comment: Absolutely perfect!  Thank you so much.